# Codeigniter, best practice for safe search

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter, and at the moment I am making full body search, and I am wondering what is the best practice to do this. For now I have this:

```
$keyword = $this->db->escape_like_str(trim($_POST['keyword']));
```

After that, search is performed. Is this safe or I need to do something more (XSS Filtering is on)?

Comment: The risk here is of sql injection, so XSS is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are accessing the _POST variable directly, you're bypassing all CI's XSS/Escaping and security features. You should be getting that as:

```
$this->input->post('keyword');
```

This is [automatically escaped by CI,](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) and you can perform other validations before just throwing it at the DB. Also if you use [active record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), then all values are automatically escaped as required too.